# set a name for pandas dataframe that created from dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have created a dataframe form dictionary:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict['data'], orient='index')
```

I have a dataframe like this:

```
            value
 10.1.1.1   aa
 10.1.1.2   bb
 10.1.1.3   cc
```

I want a data frame like this

```
 ip         value
 10.1.1.1   aa
 10.1.1.2   bb
 10.1.1.3   cc
```

methods : `set_index` doesn't give a correct answer. 
How can I add an index like second dataframe?

Comment: Do you want to reset the index or just name the index?

Comment: set a new name. But this time I have 3 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
df.index.name = 'ip'
```

or

```
df = df.rename_axis('ip')
```

Then, you may want to `reset_index`:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         ip value
0  10.1.1.1    aa
1  10.1.1.2    bb
2  10.1.1.3    cc
```

Comment: print df.index.names output is [None]

Comment: Don't do the the reset_index().

Comment: rename_axis is none, but df.index.name = 'ip' is ok

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can reset_index and rename the column:

```
In [23]: df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'ip'})

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
         ip value
0  10.1.1.1    aa
1  10.1.1.2    bb
2  10.1.1.3    cc
```